# Laravel Collection: How to access object of object?

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent, resources

This is my query:

```
$productItems = ProductItemResource::collection(ProductItem::where('pd_id', $id)->get());
```

The output of query is this:

```
$output = [[
            'id' => 1,
            'serial' => "XXXXXXAA1",
            'pd_item_info' =>[
                'id' => 1,
                'quantity' => 5,
                'product_info' => [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'product_name' => 'Keyboard'
                ],
            ]
    ],[
        'id' => 2,
        'serial' => "XXXXXXAA2",
        'pd_item_info' =>[
            'id' => 2,
            'quantity' => 10,
            'product_info' => [
                'id' => 2,
                'product_name' => 'Monitor'
            ],
        ]
    ]];
```

This is my condition:

```
    foreach ($output as $productItem) {
            return $productItem->pd_item_info->product_info['product_name'];
// IT HAS AN ERROR WHERE I CAN'T ACCESS THE OBJECT OF OBJECT

        }
```

Why I'm getting error accessing object of object when I use resource?

Comment: is `pd_item_info` an object or an array?

Comment: Why use a Resource collection if your goal is to further manipulate in php?

Comment: pd_item_info is an object

Comment: Devon, I need to get the product name and serial. So to do that I need to use resource to get the product name

Comment: I doubt you need to use a resource to do this... use the model and the relationship like you're supposed to.  Also, provide a real dump of the result, so we can see the actual data types.  It looks like arrays, not objects here.

Answer (score 0):

that the result is an array is not an object.

```
foreach($output as productItem) {
    return $productItem['pd_item_info']['product_info']['product_name'];
}
```

Comment: I use that code yesterday but it doesn't work that way

Answer (score 0):

Why you create a new collection?

```
$productItems = ProductItemResource::collection(ProductItem::where('pd_id', $id)->get());
```

Result of query already is collection

```
ProductItem::where('pd_id', $id)->get()
```